# creating git repositories from live [wordpress,magento] sites, ignoring core php files, but be able to clone the repository on multiple local servers

Tags: wordpress, git, magento, repository, localhost

So I have a lot of websites, 150+. Starting with the bigger sites I am beginning to set up git repositories for tracking the changes to these sites. I can create a localserver version of a site and set up the repository and everything is running fine.

I have set up a .gitignore file to ignore all the core files and plugin folders etc. Again this is fine, the files are still on my local machine and have been deleted from my repository.

What I want to do is set up this repository on multiple computers (my colleagues who do less development work but will still need access to the repository). I imagine cloning won't work as all the core files are no longer in repository. How do I get around this?

Thanks all!

EDIT:

I should have mentioned we're using BitBucket to act as a central repository if that makes any difference.

Comment: I'd have 2 .git projects: one with the core files (e.g. a default install of WP) and one with your non-core files. A script to put them together might do the trick then...

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways you can do that.

1. You can set local environment in one location, and keep git repository in other location.
   After cloning or pulling the repository you can then run script which will copy the files from repository to the local environment.
2. You can add all files to the repository ignoring only var/, .htaccess, app/etc/local.xml and .gitignore. Bare in mind that you can break a website by changing files which should not have been changed. Debugging then becomes a nightmare. Having all in git, you know instantly what went wrong.

We've managed to set up great workflow using beanstalk.com. They've got option to share repositories (like github) and then deploying them on different server through SSH. Works like a charm - highly recommended.